# Syncing Sent / inbox folder in Gmail with outlook 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2013

My laptop was stolen recently and I had my last back up done in Jan, 2014. I have .pst files for my out look from my last backup. I want to download all the emails in my google mail server account both inbox and sent emails to my outlook 2013.

Please suggest the best way of doing this without sending up with duplicates.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

If you have never removed (downloaded and removed server copy) from your gmail account, there is no need for your PST file(s).

Simply set up an IMAP connection to your gmail account from Outlook 2013. Once you have all your email, you can then copy then export the data to a PST file: http://www.cumc.columbia.edu/it/howto/email/exp13.html

Note that if this is a paid Google Apps account, Google offers a tool for Exchange Active Sync: https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gappssync